# Drupal update.php white screening

Tags: drupal

Tried everything..

Permissions, error logs, re-cloning, etc.

Works fine on another workstation so can't be the application code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Upload some small script containing only `phpinfo();` call, find out what php.ini file is used and edit it. Turn on error display. If web server is working it can't return empty screen - there must by some error message if errors are enabled.

Comment: Try uploading some file (i.e. some image) and accessing it from browser. Can you see the image? That is...do you face white screen only when calling update.php or every call to domain ends with white screen?

Comment: Also, use Firebug or some similar tool and check response you get.

Comment: No every call  white screens, just update.php and the admin pages. (Not the Admin login though, strangely.

Comment: Hmm...strange. Try creating another small php file with some error, i.e. try calling some non existing function to see what will happen. Will you get an error message or white screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just to further expand on this.

- Local setup of Drupal
- All the front-end pages work
- Can login as a user or admin successfully at the URL '/user'
- Colleague has followed the exact same process and works fine for him
- Cannot access any page that has URL '/admin/...'

Tried everything...

- .htaccess file from fresh Drupal install
- .htaccess file from working local copy on colleagues machine
- .htaccess file from working other local Drupal build that works
- Increased php.ini memory limit to 256m
- WAMP server apache rewrite_module is turned on
- etc...

Whats really strange is that I have other Drupal builds locally that work fine.